# create a variable name for existing variable in php

Tags: php, sql, variables, insert

Hi i have a variables that names are

```
$variable1='content1' , $variable2='content2' , $variable3='content3';
```

and i need to loop for using that contents and index for that; example;

```
$index=3;
for($i=0;$i<=$index;$i++){

  $sql="insert into table values("'variable'.$i,$i")on duplicate key update variable=values(variable),controlValueThatIs$i=values(controlValueThatIs$i)";
  $mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
```

Is that work?

Comment: INSERT has no WHERE clause. Perhaps you want UPDATE instead?

Comment: for the sake of god **don't** use mysql_ anymore, it's deprecated and not safe, use mysqli_ instead. Here's a [LINK](http://digitizor.com/2013/07/10/mysqli-vs-mysql/), if you want to change

Comment: actually im using insert or update and mysqli_query in my original code but im trying to explain my problem in easy way so there is some code mistakes

Comment: ok, then i'm sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

`$str = 'variable'.$i;`

`echo $$str;`

Comment: It inserts to database like '$variable1' not content of variable1 :(

Answer (score 2):

the problem is quote (') you should use it along with whole variable name like this -

```
values("'variable".$i."')
```